# Comparing current values with last values in architecture component

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am getting a complex `json` from an `api` and I am saving the values with `Architect component(Room)`.

Question:

- Can I compare current values with last values that I saved in `SQlite` and if in compare I find a difference, update the `RecyclerView`?
- Is this method logical?
- Do you have a better way to offer?
- If you have a better way to offer get me a sample(url sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that and it is actually the recommended way. In order to do so, I think you should leverage the use of two other Architecture Components that were introduced with Android Jetpack, not only `Room` database: [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), but it is not mandatory.

The important thing is to add an extra layer to your app called `Repository`:

> **Repository** modules handle data operations. They provide a clean API so
>   that the rest of the app can retrieve this data easily. They know
>   where to get the data from and what API calls to make when data is
>   updated. You can consider repositories to be mediators between
>   different data sources, such as persistent models, web services, and
>   caches.

So basically, the suggested architecture to handle this will look something like this:

[image: Android recommended architecture]

With that in mind, an example of a Repository that retrieves User data from a web service and save it to a local Room Database will look something like this:

```
public class UserRepository {
    private final Webservice webservice;
    private final UserDao userDao;
    private final Executor executor;

    public UserRepository(Webservice webservice, UserDao userDao, Executor executor) {
        this.webservice = webservice;
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser(String userId) {
        refreshUser(userId);
        // Returns a LiveData object directly from the database.
        return userDao.load(userId);
    }

    private void refreshUser(final String userId) {
        // Runs in a background thread.
        executor.execute(() -> {
            // Check if user data was fetched recently.
            boolean userExists = userDao.hasUser(FRESH_TIMEOUT);
            if (!userExists) {
                // Refreshes the data.
                Response<User> response = webservice.getUser(userId).execute();

                // Check for errors here.

                // Updates the database. The LiveData object automatically
                // refreshes, so we don't need to do anything else here.
                userDao.save(response.body());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, your ViewModel will get the User Live Data doing something like this:

```
...
user = userRepo.getUser(userId);
...
```

And it will provide that LiveData to the UI layer with a public method:

```
...
public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        return this.user;
}
...
```

Finally, from your UI layer (an Activity or Fragment) you can **observe** the LiveData in the ViewModel and adapt the UI accordingly.

```
viewModel.getUser().observe(this, user -> {
      // Update UI.
});
```

For a more complete explanation I suggest that you take a look to:

1. [Guide to app architecture in Android`s Developers website.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)
2. [This Github project with a basic example.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample)
3. [This other Github project with a more complex example.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)

Comment: @ dglozano. I am using from above your source code but how can I compare values???

Comment: @jojo why do you want to compare? it is unnecessary. If you have an entity saved on your phone's database and you get that same user from a web service you should update your local user with whatever info you get from the web (because that's where the most recent information about that entity should be). If the information of the user that was fetched from the internet was the same as the information you already had in the DB, it will be overwritten and nothing will change. Instead, if the information is different, the local user will be overwritten with the new information.

Comment: However, if you for some reason want to do some comparison between the recently fetched information and the local information, in my example you could do it where it says `// Check for errors here`. Use your `userDao` to get the local user and compare it with the response from the web, and then apply whatever logic you want

Comment: Ok. Thank's a lot.

Comment: @jojo you are welcome. Make sure to check the last github repository I put at the end of the answer. There you have a big and complete example. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can merge multiple live data source from server and sqlite with MediatorLiveData which is a subclass of LiveData.

For example, if you have a LiveData object in your UI that can be updated from a local database or a network, then you can add the following sources to the MediatorLiveData object:

```
A LiveData object associated with the data stored in the database.
A LiveData object associated with the data accessed from the network.
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java)